# Specifying file path in grunt

Tags: npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using grunt for minification and npm for managing plugins. I have given  my grunt configuration below.

```
    //Grunt configuration
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

      grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


        uglify: {


          core_modules: {
            options: {
              beautify: false
            },
            files: {
              'resources/dist/core.min.js': [   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular/angular.js",
                                                "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
                                                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                                                "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js",
                                                "node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js"
],
            },
          },


        },

      });

      //Grunt Plugins
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


      //Default Tasks
      grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
    }
```

if I give "node_modules/**/*.js" it is minifying all the files so Im giving the files path in array format. Is there any way to do it easily?

Answer (score 0):

Can declare a variable with those files and give the variable as value to dest,

```
var files= [   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular/angular.js",
                                                "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
                                                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                                                "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
                                                "node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js",
                                                "node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js"
];
 //Grunt configuration
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

      grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


        uglify: {


          core_modules: {
            options: {
              beautify: false
            },
            files: {
              'resources/dist/core.min.js': files,
            },
          },


        },

      });

      //Grunt Plugins
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


      //Default Tasks
      grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
    }
```